# How to use sockepath in mysql and nodejs connection

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sockets

I am trying to create a connection between mysql and nodejs using mysql's socketPath instead of using the host type.

Here is my file that tries to connect to mysql using nodejs

```
require('dotenv').config()
const mysql = require('mysql');

const myDB = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 50,
    socketPath: '/var/tmp/mysql.sock',
    user: 'userdbuser02',
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DATABASE
});

myDB.getConnection((error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(`Successfully connected at ${process.env.DATABASE}`);
    }
});

module.exports = myDB;
```

And it gives me this error:

> sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MariaDB client',

**NOTE:** I am using Mysql 5.6 version and I don't know why it gives me MariaDB error

Comment: What MariaDB version? What npm mysql version? What is the `SHOW CREATE 'hmidbuser02'@'localhost'`definition in SQL for this user?

Comment: Hi @danblack I've updated the question

Comment: The error is generated on the server side, so its definitely connecting to a mariadb server. [SHOW CREATE USER](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-create-user/) was added in 10.2 and I don't see that answer. Which [npm mysql version](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/master/Changes.md) seems to have a 2.17.0 fix on authentication however how the user is created would matter there too.